# C# restart function if caught exception

Tags: c#, exception

I have a function enclosed in try catch that I would like to redo if there was an exception but time from start of the function is less than 1 hour.  How to implement this, should I use some sort of loop?

```
public void myFunct()
{
    // start timer
    try
    {
        // do some work
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // if timer less than 1 hour, go to start of try
    }
}
```

Comment: "*but time from start of the function is less than 1 hour*" - what does this mean? also consider Polly

Comment: Yeah, Polly would be a good option. Or just a simple loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void myFunct()
{
    bool restart;
    var startTimer = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
    do
    {
        restart = false;
        startTimer.Start();
        try
        {
            // do some work
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            startTimer.Stop();
            if (startTimer.Elapsed.Hours < 1)
            {
                restart = true;
                startTimer.Reset();
            }
        }
    } while (restart);
}
```